# Nuxt3 Vite support for Cypress coverage instrumentation

Tags: cypress, vite, instrumentation, nuxtjs3, istanbul

I am building a Nuxt3 app and trying to integrate Cypress. As I'm aware Nuxt3 uses Vite instead and not babel, I was trying to instrument the project code using `vite-plugin-istanbul` npm package.

Here's my `nuxt.config.ts` after installing `vite-plugin-istanbul` package:

```js
vite: {
  vue: {
    template: {
      transformAssetUrls: true
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    istanbul({
      exclude: ['node_modules', 'test/', 'coverage/'],
      extension: [ '.js', '.ts', '.vue' ],
      cypress: true
    }),
  ]
},
```

When I'm trying to run the server using `npm run dev` and visit the localhost URL, the following error is thrown at terminal:

```bash
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] window is not defined
  at cov_1291n0zka8 (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:3623:191)  
  at $id_Sv05hbOoTf (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:3624:75)  
  at async __instantiateModule__ (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:40418:3)
```

It seems the plugin is instrumenting the server-side rendered code and `window` object isn't defined there. I need to have SSR enabled in my app and I'm not sure of how to handle this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by the plugin authors.

#### TLDR version

Just update the `vite-plugin-istanbul` package to the [latest version](https://github.com/iFaxity/vite-plugin-istanbul) and the issue should get resolved.

#### Long version

There are two parts to this error:

1. The package was originally configured to transform all the files. The plugin authors have now added a condition that checks whether the SSR has been enabled or not. This is done via `options.ssr` property within the transform function. Please upgrade to the latest version of `vite-plugin-istanbul`. The plugin no longer instruments the SSR files, hence the window object error no longer exists in there. [Follow this thread if you need more details.](https://github.com/iFaxity/vite-plugin-istanbul/issues/50)
2. After getting this error resolved, I was still facing another issue where the code instrumentation was impacting the proper app compilation and throwing a hydration mismatch error. The plugin authors came to the rescue again and fixed this error. Please upgrade to the latest version of `vite-plugin-istanbul`. [Follow this GitHub thread if you need more details.](https://github.com/iFaxity/vite-plugin-istanbul/issues/60)

The package authors are really awesome and helpful. It's great to see such people in the open source community!